# MVC 3 Global condition check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a Function Which returns true/false...Something Like this....

```
Shared Function CartHasItems() As Boolean
    If HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    Else
        If CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart"), ShoppingCart).Items.Count > 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Now on few pages I have to check wether this function retuens true/false...if FALSE then show a message and redirect to a page...if TRUE then nothing happens.

my problem is...I have so many Pages(VIEWS), where I have to call this function to do the condition check and do the processing....for now I am doing it manually like this....

```
<% If ViewData("CartSession") Then %>
      We have Items
    <% Else %>
       No Items
    <% End If%>
```

I can tell, this is not the proper way of doing it....there are so many views, and it looks like i am repeating my code over and over again.

in webforms i used BASE CLASS, I used the page_load event of base class to do repetitive tasks, how could I do this in MVC on selected set of views?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this in the page?  Why not in the controller?  You could then add this functionality to a base controller you inherit from, or as an attribute you can place on the action method (or even controller).

Comment: any related examples would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit Goes to "Mystere Man" for putting me in right direction. **ActionFilterAttribute** was the Answer...I created a **Custom Action Filter**....Now I can apply the action filter to any Action Method or even on the entire controller. below is the Code sample.

```
Public Class CartCheckFilter
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute


    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)

        If HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") Is Nothing Then

            Dim redirectTarget = New RouteValueDictionary() From { _
             {"action", "noCartData"}, _
             {"controller", "Checkout"} _
            }

            filterContext.Result = New RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTarget)

        Else

            If CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart"), ShoppingCart).Items.Count <= 0 Then

                Dim redirectTarget = New RouteValueDictionary() From { _
                 {"action", "noCartData"}, _
                 {"controller", "checkout"} _
                }

                filterContext.Result = New RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTarget)
            End If


        End If



    End Sub
```

And This is how I can implement this ActionFilter:

```
<CartCheckFilter()>
Function Index() As ActionResult

    Return View()

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Write an extension method that extends HtmlHelper.

For more information on how to do so: http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/

**Update**

You can also put that logic in a Paris view in the Shared views directory.

Alternatively you can create a base class for all of your views and put it there: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

Comment: Extension method may string a string or boolean for me...my GOAL is to show a message and stop processing of the page....this way i still have to do a check with if ELSE statement. for example...if no items in cart SHOW MESSAGE and dont render page content during billto/shipto page.

Comment: Then move that check to a partial view which will be the the Shared views directory.

Comment: if I have view called "Index", can I only load the partialview into it (which has all the conditions into it) and IGNORE the rest of the page?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why does the if else condition bothers you so much?

Comment: IF TRUE THEN show some stuff ELSE show the FORM END IF, basically its an if else which needs to be on every page, i am writing if else for every single page....ELSE for some pages contains FORM, for some pages plain text etc. so just looking for BEST practice to avoid repetitive code.

Comment: Send the content of the else clause to the partial view through its model